# Troubleshooting JS Shipping Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript

Is you'll probably be able to tell I'm a complete JS rookie but I've spent my day working on this code to display a shipping timer, compiled from bits of various other posts on SO (thanks!).

It seemed to be going well until I completed adding all the functionality I needed and now it's not working. When you first run the snippet it works correctly but as soon as it ticks the "day" value displays incorrectly (it should display 'tomorrow' but it switches to 'today') and the timer itself has stopped counting down.

I can't figure out for the life of me where I messed it up so looking for some assistance if possible! Thanks in advance.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c3otusv6/

```
(function() {
var start = new Date();
start.setHours(14, 0, 0);

var maybePluralize = function maybePluralize(count, noun) {
    var suffix = arguments.length <= 2 || arguments[2] === undefined ? 's' : arguments[2];
    return count + ' ' + noun + (count !== 1 ? suffix : '');
};

var now = new Date();
var day = now.getDay();

function tick() {

    if (day >= 1 && day <= 5 && now < start) {
        document.getElementById('ddate').innerHTML = 'today';
    } else if (day >= 1 && day <= 4 && now >= start || day == 7) {
        document.getElementById('ddate').innerHTML = 'tomorrow';
    } else if (day == 5 && now >= start || day == 6) {
        document.getElementById('ddate').innerHTML = 'Monday';
    }

    if (day == 6 || day == 5 && now > start || day == 7 && now < start) {
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "now";
    } else {
        if (now > start) { // too late, go to tomorrow
            start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
        }
        var remain = (start - now) / 1000;
        var hh = Math.floor(remain / 60 / 60 % 60);
        var mm = Math.floor(remain / 60 % 60);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "in the next <strong>" + maybePluralize(hh, 'hour') + " " + maybePluralize(mm, 'min') + "</strong>";

        setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tick);
```

})();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have the function called every second, you need to use `setInterval`. `setTimeout` just runs the given function **once** after the specified number of seconds.

I have made small edit to you fiddle, to make it run every second.

As for the "day" value being incorrect, I think you need to check your `if` statements. I quite dont understand your business logic.

**Also note - Sunday is given by '0' in getDay.** And I see you using `day == 7`, so you might want to check that and do the necessary adjustments. I guess you need to -1 from all your if statements for day.

http://jsfiddle.net/wm9kj8yb/

```js
(function() {
  var start = new Date();
  var now = new Date();
  var day = now.getDay();
  start.setHours(14, 0, 0);

  function maybePluralize(count, noun) {
    var suffix = arguments.length <= 2 || arguments[2] === undefined ? 's' : arguments[2];
    return count + ' ' + noun + (count !== 1 ? suffix : '');
  };

  function tick() {
    now = new Date();
    day = now.getDay();
    if (day >= 1 && day <= 5 && now < start) {
      document.getElementById('ddate').innerHTML = 'today';
    } else if (day >= 1 && day <= 4 && now >= start || day == 7) {
      document.getElementById('ddate').innerHTML = 'tomorrow';
    } else if (day == 5 && now >= start || day == 6) {
      document.getElementById('ddate').innerHTML = 'Monday';
    }

    if (day == 6 || day == 5 && now > start || day == 7 && now < start) {
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "now";
    } else {

      if (now > start) { // too late, go to tomorrow
        start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
      }
      var remain = (start - now) / 1000;
      var ss = Math.floor(remain % 60);
      remain = Math.floor(remain / 60);
      var mm = remain % 60;
      remain = Math.floor(remain / 60);
      var hh = remain % 60;
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "in the next <strong>" + maybePluralize(hh, 'hour') + " " + maybePluralize(mm, 'min') + " " + " " + maybePluralize(ss, 'sec') + "</strong>";

    }
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    setInterval(tick, 1000);
  });
})();
```

```html
Order <span id='countdown'></span> for dispatch <span id='ddate'></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I had no idea about the Sunday = 0 thing. I only need to call the function every minute but I lowered the interval for debugging purposes. I've been playing around with the code some more and it seems the if statement "if (now > start) { start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);" was screwing with the function for the day output too. Until I get better at JS i've removed the functionality and seems to be working fine now - http://jsfiddle.net/k7fdm216/2/

Comment: Welcome, also check your setInterval usage, you need to put it in the correct place

Comment: Oh ok. These are language specific things, like getDay. I would recommend checking MDN whenever you are using a new functionality/method and get stuck.